# Deleting cookies file after CasperJS script finished

Tags: javascript, file, phantomjs, casperjs, fs

I want to use `fs` library to create a file at the begin of my script and delete it at the end. The `cookies.txt` file is created at the begin but not deleted at the end of the script..

```
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
var fs = require('fs');
var cookies = JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies);
fs.write("cookies.txt", cookies, 777); // THIS WORKS !!

casper.start('http://google.fr/', function(){
    this.viewport(320, 480);
});
// my script ....
casper.then(function(){
    fs.remove("cookies.txt"); // THIS NOT WORKS !!
});
casper.run(function() {
    this.test.done();
    this.exit();
});
```

The command I write to start the script

```
casperjs test lbc.js --cookies-file=cookies.txt --web-security=no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but it happens so fast that you can't see that it really works.

You start casper with the `cookies-file` option (see the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html)). This means that you want the cookies to persist after the script has exited to use them at the next invocation.

When you `exit` casper (and phantom for that matter) the cookies file is written to disk, but this happens after you deleted the file with `fs.remove("cookies.txt");`. So the file is actually deleted and then rewritten.

The question is, what do you want to do?